# Why can we edit posts if the edit queue is full?

Tags: support, edits, suggested-edits

I have been getting this annoying error when I am going through my review queue. I see that some posts need editing in formatting, spelling, grammar, etc., and I make my changes. Depending on the question, it might take some time and effort, and when I press submit button, it just throws the error that the edit queue is full. It is frustrating because I spent time making changes for nothing. It is also unknown when the queue won't be full, and I can submit my changes. Because of that, I skip post-editing and either approve it or share feedback now.

So why do we even have the possibility to edit the post if it is not available for edit? Wouldn't it be better to block post-editing when the queue is full?

Comment: Hmm.. if you can't edit it, you need to Skip the review and let someone else edit it. Don't do another action because you can't do the required one. It's not about "your review", it's about reviewing being put in place to make the site better.

Comment: Other people *can* edit without review (>=2k rep); certainly we shouldn't block post-editing for them?

Comment: @Scratte the thing is, I already completed my edits, and I didn't know that queue was full. So I just wasted my time making changes to the original post. This is the main issue for me. Some posts are understandable but only need some formatting and maybe grammar fixes, and as a reviewer, I get an option to edit the post to make it better, which is not available but shown as so.

Comment: Yes, I understand the issue. But at that point you'll still need to Skip it. You could just Skip all post that needs an edit. I did that when I did most of my reviewing.. since the queue is almost always full.

Comment: Yeah, have to second Scratte here - if you can't edit, "skip", tough luck - we have suggested edits cluttered with typo fixes, irrelevant tags, and other "good" stuff, unfortunately. It's been near its capacity every day for a long time, and recent changes to review queues did not help much in brining new reviewers. That said, well, we hear you, it is annoying as hell (even users with 5K+ can't edit tag wikis without going through the queue, and getting "the queue is full" after carefully constructing one is baffling). There is little to be done, though - after all, queues are an async [1/2]

Comment: [2/2] process. You can start editing at 497 review tasks and finish when 3 more tasks have already been poured into the queue from other places. What should happen in this case? 'tis a non-trivial problem. It is solvable (i.e. give priority for edits incoming from other queues) but not easy and, frankly, at this point I do not trust Stack to be capable of solving non-trivial problems.

Comment: @OlegValter The number is cached. You can easily see 386 posts in the queue, while getting the message. So it's not even possible to prepare properly for it :(

Comment: @Scratte I know, but please, read the message again, is not about user perception :) It's about the real state of things. Agreed that there is probably close to impossible to solve. However, I do not believe it is *completely* impossible given that the queue state can be passed around live with WS instead

Comment: "So why do we even have the possibility to edit the post if it is not available for edit?" - well it's hard to predict the future. The only blocker would be if the queue would be full the moment you hit the submit button, not when you open a piece of content for editing... I do that quite frequently without the actual intent of committing any edits too, I do it to see the raw post content before it is rendered by the Matrix.

Comment: @Gimby I think it is possible to return the current state of the post and make the edit button unavailable. Of course, I don't know how the database works in StackOverflow's backend but adding this feature would add a great user experience.

Comment: @Raguel what if when you click "edit" the queue is not full, but it's full by the time you are done with your edit? What then?

Comment: @yivi Then the problem wouldn't be 100% solved, but it would _still_ be better than what we have now, and would foreseeably waste a few less people's time.

Comment: @HereticMonkey We need the edit to be disabled for <2k rep because denying the edit _ex post facto_ is strong discouraging and disincentivizing edits on all posts in the review. If I don't know beforehand whether my edits will be rejected because of full queue, I am less likely to submit any edits and eventually I just stop reviewing altogether.

Comment: @MavaddatJavid My comment (from 2+ years ago) was against disabling the edit button for users with >= 2k rep.  I'm not sure why you're responding to that comment with discussion about what needs to happen for users with < 2k rep... on a closed question.

Comment: @HereticMonkey, my apologies. I misread your previous comment. I was trying to agree with what I thought was your point (that the edit button should be disabled when the edit queue is full). I was lacking sleep.