# Why doesn't SO block the edit option if the edit queue is already full and why can't we have a read access to the edit queue in review queue?

Tags: support, edits, suggested-edits

For the first time I went to the First Answer Stack Overflow Queue.

I got my first review and selected

[image: image of option labeled "Edit - Improve and correct problems with this answer yourself"]

because the answer needed proper formatting. I spent my time adding all this format and pressed *Save edits*. But the edit queue was full and I lost all my progress, because I couldn't keep my browser open for ages.

[image: image of dialog explaining the edit queue is full]

Why doesn't Stack Overflow block the edit option if the queue is already full?

I see that there is already [a question about it](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/411810/why-can-we-edit-posts-if-the-edit-queue-is-full), but it's closed and links to another questions which explain why there is a limit for edits (???). I understand that there should be a limit, but users shouldn't be able to edit in the review queue if their change can't be sent. It's *very* frustrating.

Moreover if the queue is full it's maybe because the changes are all similar... Since we can't see what are the suggested edit from other reviewers we may send the same edit suggestions multiple times if it's obvious. Why can't we have a **read-only** access to the edit queue to avoid editing the same things multiple times?

Comment: "*Why doesn't stack overflow block the edit option if the queue is already full ?*" What if it becomes full after you've started to edit? Then we're back to square one. "*I see that there is already a question about it but it's closed and links to another questions which explain why there is a limit for edits (???).*" honestly - that's much more a problem with SE than showing or hiding the edit option. The latter is a bandaid, the real problem is the constantly high numbers of reviews. This desperately needs solving. Anything else is temporary at best.

Comment: I don't have access to review queue but for the some example I saw where edit queue was full, the question was short enough for me to think that a lot of people just proposed the same edit multiple times. That's why I'm wondering why we can check in read only mode the edit queue

Comment: "Why doesn't stack overflow block the edit option if the queue is already full ?" - they do, but they don't reserve your spot when you click "edit". If the edit queue fills up again while you're editing, you won't be allowed to submit it for a few minutes. You also already have read-only access to the queues ([but not directly through the UI](https://stackoverflow.com/review/), because reasons I guess; but beware of caching).

Comment: Also, it seems you may have misunderstood, ref "to avoid editing the same things multiple times ?"; only one suggested edit is allowed per post, and that's a different error message. Access to the review queue won't help with that either

Comment: @Butanium the edit queue is not *for one post*. It wasn't that few people decided to edit the same question as you. It's for all questions, all answers, all tag wikis. There is a limit of 500 items for the review queue over *all posts* on SO from all the time. All suggested edits (for posts - edits from users with less than 2k rep, for tags - edits from users with less than 20k rep) need to be reviewed.

Comment: Yep. if the question has a pending suggested edit, you'll be blocked for a different reason, and have to wait for it to be reviewed, instead of for the queue to be reviewed down a bit. There's a site-wide cap of 500 pending suggested edits across all posts, for all users. You're additionally constrained to 5 pending edits that you've made, but again, different error.

Comment: Oh yes, sorry, I didn't understand that the review was for the whole website...

Comment: If the edit queue is often full should I avoid edits that are only adding some backticks ?

Comment: @Butanium You should avoid edits that are only adding some backticks all the time (unless of course that's all there is to fix). Your edits should attempt to fix _all_ issues in the posts.

Comment: ok thanks for all those clarifications, should I delete this question ?

Comment: Nah, this question isn't doing any harm.

Comment: Please do not edit in answers into the question - if you want, feel free to post and accept your conclusion as an answer instead, that's the usual way to go

Comment: Re *"I couldn't keep my browser open for ages"*: Couldn't you save it offline? Alternatively, somewhere on the Internet, like a private wiki on [Wikidot](http://www.wikidot.com/) or [CodePen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CodePen) (or similar).

Answer (score 9):

When I first started editing posts, [I found the limit on suggested edits frustrating too](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/396865/how-long-is-the-suggested-edit-wait-usually).

It's necessary to limit the number of edits from new users coming in to SO somehow, because they need to be reviewed by more experienced community members.

Personally, I was annoyed that I had spent time editing a post, and I was prevented from suggesting my edit by a queue which I had no control over, and which I could not see.

I should also say that the small reputation boost played no small part in motivating me to suggest edits to posts.

Now, as a user with sufficient reputation to access review queues, I find it frustrating how full the review queues are.

The flip-side of the Suggested Edit queue is the First Questions queue. As of writing, the Suggested Edit queue has 481 items for review, and the First Questions queue has 15,600.

This [has been raised](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/411502/the-backlog-of-reviews-in-the-first-questions-review-queue-is-increasing) [multiple times](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/415761/the-backlog-of-reviews-in-the-first-questions-review-queue-is-still-increasing), and the queue is still massive. It can be 2 weeks before a first question makes it to the top of the queue.

The solutions here are two sides of the same coin. SO doesn't limit first questions, because questions and answers are the primary value offering of the website. SO does limit the number of edits which can be suggested by low-rep users, because those edits are likely to be fairly minor and not significantly change the value of a Q&A to the majority of readers.

At the heart of it, to address these issues, SO needs to increase the amount of moderation happening, and decrease the amount of content which needs manual moderation. There's (probably) no silver bullet here.

All I can say is ask some good questions, and write some good answers. [Eventually your edits get applied immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit), and you can help other users who are in your situation by reviewing their edits.

Comment: The point is: Is a user active for years with a reputation of more than 2000 actually a "new user"? And the other thing is that successful reviews do not give you any increased reputation; maybe that's why few people want to invest a lot of time working on the review queue. maybe also the review queues should be consider the reputation of a user when sorting, so that "quality edits" are considered first; maybe also such edits can be handled faster than posts with a seemingly endless list of issues.